# How can I add a CSS class with an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a CSS class with an `onclick` event using JavaScript.

This is my html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="weekly.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sf_new_calendar_weekly_container">
        <div class="sf_day_card">
            <div class="sf_day_card_heading">
                    <h5>MON</h5>
                    <p>January 9</p>
            </div>
            <div class="events">
                <div class="sf_parks_hours">
                    <div class="sf_general_hours">

                    </div>
                    <div class="sf_park_events_hours">

                    </div>
                    <div class="sf_park_events_hours">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="sf_day_card">
            <div class="sf_day_card_heading">
                    <h5>TUE</h5>
                    <p>January 10</p>
            </div>
            <div class="events"><div class="sf_parks_hours">
                <div class="sf_general_hours">

                </div>
                <div class="sf_park_events_hours">

                </div>
                <div class="sf_park_events_hours"></div>
            </div></div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="sf_day_card">
            <div class="sf_day_card_heading">
                    <h5>WED</h5>
                    <p>January 11</p>
            </div>
            <div class="events">
                <div class="sf_parks_hours">
                    <div class="sf_general_hours">

                    </div>
                    <div class="sf_park_events_hours">

                    </div>
                    <div class="sf_park_events_hours">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="sf_day_card_open sf_day_card_open_yellow ">
            <div class="sf_day_card_heading bg_yellow">
                    <h5>THU</h5>
                    <p>January 12</p>
            </div>
            <div class="events">
                <div class="sf_parks_hours">
                    <div class="sf_general_hours">
                        <i class="fa-regular fa-clock"></i>
                        <p>10AM - 6PM</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sf_park_events_hours">
                        <p class="event-title">Water Park</p>
                        <p class="event-hours">10AM - 6PM</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sf_park_events_hours">
                        <p class="event-title">Safari</p>
                        <p class="event-hours">10AM - 6PM</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="sf_events">
                    <div class="sf_park_event_heading">
                        <i class="fa-regular fa-flag"></i>
                        <p class="event_name">Pass Holder Appreciation Week</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sf_park_event_heading">
                        <i class="fa-regular fa-flag"></i>
                        <p class="event_name">Christmas in the Park</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sf_day_card_open">
            <div class="sf_day_card_heading ">
                    <h5>FRI</h5>
                    <p>January 13</p>
            </div>
            <div class="events">
                <div class="sf_parks_hours">
                    <div class="sf_general_hours">
                        <i class="fa-regular fa-clock"></i>
                        <p class="event-hours">10AM - 6PM</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sf_park_events_hours">

                    </div>
                    <div class="sf_park_events_hours">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="sf_day_card_open">
            <div class="sf_day_card_heading">
                    <h5>SAT</h5>
                    <p>January 14</p>
            </div>
            <div class="events">
                <div class="sf_parks_hours">
                    <div class="sf_general_hours">
                        <i class="fa-regular fa-clock"></i>
                        <p class="event-hours">10AM - 6PM</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sf_park_events_hours">
                    </div>
                    <div class="sf_park_events_hours">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="sf_day_card">
            <div class="sf_day_card_heading">
                    <h5>SUN</h5>
                    <p>January 15</p>
            </div>
            <div class="events">
                <div class="sf_parks_hours">
                    <div class="sf_general_hours">

                    </div>
                    <div class="sf_park_events_hours">

                    </div>
                    <div class="sf_park_events_hours">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my script where I target the divs with a class that I am targetting.

```
let heading = document.querySelectorAll(".sf_day_card_heading");
```

I want to add a CSS class that changes the background color to yellow to the div that I select but I don´t know how to start with the logic.

I know I have to do a function with an `onclick` event and add the CSS class but I don't know how.

Comment: Do you want to add a class to each Div that has been selected with `querySelectorAll(".sf_day_card_heading");`?

Comment: No, sorry i was not clear. Just add the class `bg_yellow` to the div i click on that contains the class `sf_day_card_heading` @StanleyUlili

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will add a class to an element that you click and remove the class from other elements similar elements

```
let heading = document.querySelectorAll(".sf_day_card_heading");
heading.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    heading.forEach((e) => e.classList.remove('your_class_name'));
    event.target.classList.add('your_class_name'));
  });
});
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I think i get how to add the class but i want to do is to add it a i click in one of those divs. I think it should be a toggle due that i want to add it to just one div and not every div i click on

Comment: @tukitooo1998 I've updated my answer. Please check if it fits your need.

Comment: It helped but i am trying to add it in just one meaning that if i have this class activated in one div and i try to activate it in another div, the div that had the activated class before should have the class now removed

Comment: @tukitooo1998 got it! Updated!

Answer (score 1):

This may help:
At first, you need to add an id to HTML div tag:

```
<div id="dayCardHeading" class="sf_day_card_heading">
```

then add event listener in javascript:

```
let heading = document.getElementById("dayCardHeading");
heading.addEventListener("click", modifyColor);

function modifyColor() {
document.getElementById("modifyColor").style.background = "#F7B538" ;
}
```

find out more:
[Event Target addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

if it was helpful please mark it.

Comment: This isn't quite what the OP is asking for -- they want to add a CSS class for each element of a certain class, while this modifies the inline style of just a single element.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to the `document` object where you listen for `click` events. Whenever a click happens, check if the user clicked on (or within) the `.sf_day_card_heading` div. Add the class based on the result.

```
document.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const target = event.target.closest('.sf_day_card_heading');
  if (target !== null) {
    target.classList.add('bg_yellow');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
let heading = document.querySelectorAll(".sf_day_card_heading");

 function activeDiv(e) {
        heading.forEach((item) => item.classList.remove('bg_yellow'))
        e.classList.add('bg_yellow')
    }
heading.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', (e)=>activeDiv(item)))
```

In the first line, you select all the elements:

```
let heading = document.querySelectorAll(".sf_day_card_heading");
```

Next, in the `activeDiv()` , you remove each `bg_yellow` class from every element and add the class `bg_yellow` to only one element:

```
 function activeDiv(e) {
        // removes the class from every element
        heading.forEach((item) => item.classList.remove('bg_yellow'))
        // adds the class        
        e.classList.add('bg_yellow')
    }
```

Finally, you attach the `click` event to each element in the `heading` array, which calls `activeDiv()` function to add a class:

```
heading.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', (e)=>activeDiv(item)))
```

Comment: This one is correct if OP is looking to select an active element and deselect others by changing the background, but that isn't exactly what is stated in the question, even if it is perhaps what they are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

once you have the particular element in a variable you use it to access the properties. In your example, you can play with the CSS by:

```
heading.style.border = "1px solid #000";
heading.style.backgroundColor: "#fff";
```

Comment: The question is about adding a CSS class. `heading` is also a `NodeList` which doesn't have a `style` property.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the elements correctly using `document.querySelectorAll`. In order to listen to a click event on each element, you can add loop through each and add an event listener.

Event listeners work just like HTML attributes like `onclick`, but are generally considered more reliable for a number of reasons, including the fact that one element can have multiple event listeners for the same event while it can only have one `onclick` attribute.

In order to toggle a CSS class on an element, you can use [`element.classList.toggle(className)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

In your case, you can loop through the elements using a [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and add an event listener to each using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Then in the event listener, toggle the yellow CSS class:

```js
const headings = document.querySelectorAll(".sf_day_card_heading");
for (const heading of headings) {
  heading.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    // This adds the class "background-yellow" to the element. 
    // You can select the `background-yellow` class in your CSS,
    // or you can use a different class name and modify it here.
    heading.classList.toggle("background-yellow")
  });
}
```

You can use this with code like this in your CSS:

```css
.background-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```